# mongodb field that has relationship with two other fields in the same collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

is it possible to create a field in mongodb collection That sums two number with aggregate automatically (i mean that i dont have to call aggregate() each time i want it to update )
for example i have a book object

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a8f3e4895ed5e3fdca7f2ad"
    },
    "category": "action",
    "author": "x",
    "title": "action book",
    "__v": 0,
    "price": 4000,
    "taxes": 370
}
```

i want to create a **totalPrice** field that sums  price and taxes even if the price or taxes  is updated. let s say the prices is gonna change every Minute. SO how to make a relation between totalPrice = price + taxes that changes whenever price or taxes change ?

Answer (score 0):

```
          Marks.findOneAndUpdate({
              username: username,
              year: year,
              section: section,
              week: week
            }, {
              $set: {
                quizmarks: quizmarks
              }
            },
            (err, data) => {
              if (err) {
                res.json({
                  'marks table error': err
                })
              } else {
                User.findOneAndUpdate({
                  username: username,
                  year: year,
                  section: section
                }, {
                  $inc: {
                    quizmarks: quizmarks,
                  },
                  $push:
                  {
                    attemptedQuizWeeks:attemptedQuizWeek
                  }
                }, (err, userdata) => {
                  if (err) {
                    res.json({
                      'usertable error': err
                    })
                  } else {
                    res.json({
                      "userdata": userdata,
                      "data": data
                    })
                  }

                })
              }
            })



        })
```

Hope this helps. Use $inc to increment the particular field you want to with value on the right handed side

Comment: i didnt quite understand this code. can you explain more please ?

Comment: i have a collection named Marks with few fileds(you could see them above).Iam finding a unique document based on username,year,section and week and updating the quizmarks .Upon success of this operation i go to another Collection User and find a unique collection based on username,year and section.Then I increment the quizmarks this way $inc: {
                    quizmarks: quizmarks,
                  }        quizmarks on the right hand are from request payload.

Comment: function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}    check this out :) @19999999views

Comment: so acording to what i understood from this code, you need to call the getNextSequence function each time you want to update your collection fields is that right ? well i was searching for something that makes a fields automatically changes whenever other fields changes. it means that a field has a relationship with other fields and it depends on them.

Comment: any ideas about how to achieve this  ? :)